# How to use Sugarcrm\Sugarcrm\Util\Uuid::uuid1() in a custom entry point?

Tags: sugarcrm, suitecrm

I am learning suitecrm. I need to create a new bean using a specific id from a custom entry point, generating the id is not working, when i try this code

```
// Create bean
$testAccountBean = BeanFactory::newBean('Accounts');

// Set the new flag
$testAccountBean->new_with_id = true;

$id = Sugarcrm\Sugarcrm\Util\Uuid::uuid1();

$testAccountBean->id = $id;
$testAccountBean->name = generateRandomString();

$testAccountBeanId = $testAccountBean->save();

echo $testAccountBeanId;
```

I get nothing

When I inspect the result of calling `Sugarcrm\Sugarcrm\Util\Uuid::uuid1()` nothing get in return.

Thanks for any idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function is called create_guid, require the `include/utils.php` and you will be able to call it.

```
<?php
 if (!defined('sugarEntry')) {
    define('sugarEntry', true);
}

require_once 'data/BeanFactory.php';
require_once 'include/utils.php';
$testAccountBean = BeanFactory::newBean('Accounts');
$id = create_guid();
```

Having said so - If you do `$testAccountBean->new_with_id = true;` it means you will provide your own ID, we use that to insert IDs from other systems/migrations. But if you need the GUID just remove that line and suitecrm will generate it for you.

Comment: Thanks for answering and the clarification for context of when using `$testAccountBean->new_with_id = true;`

Answer (score 1):

You will need to call it in following manner:

```
$testAccountBean->new_with_id = true; 
$testAccountBean->id = create_guid();
```

Note that if you assigned your own ID using create_guid function then "new_with_id" need to be set as well. You can find function at  this path: *include\utils.php*

Following is the function body:

```
function create_guid()
{
    $microTime = microtime();
    list($a_dec, $a_sec) = explode(' ', $microTime);

    $dec_hex = dechex($a_dec * 1000000);
    $sec_hex = dechex($a_sec);

    ensure_length($dec_hex, 5);
    ensure_length($sec_hex, 6);

    $guid = '';
    $guid .= $dec_hex;
    $guid .= create_guid_section(3);
    $guid .= '-';
    $guid .= create_guid_section(4);
    $guid .= '-';
    $guid .= create_guid_section(4);
    $guid .= '-';
    $guid .= create_guid_section(4);
    $guid .= '-';
    $guid .= $sec_hex;
    $guid .= create_guid_section(6);

    return $guid;
}
```